# searchStudentDetails() method does not show data how can i fetch the particular name details?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```java
public void searchStudentDetails() throws SQLException {

    DatabaseConnection dbms=new DatabaseConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Studentdb","root","root");
    Connection con= dbms.getConnection();
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    String inputname=obj.next();
    String sql="select *from student where name=? ";
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    stmt.setString(1, inputname);
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next() ==false)
    {
    System.out.println("no such data is found");
    }
    else
    {
        while(rs.next())
        {
            rs.previous();
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)+" "+rs.getInt(4));
        }
    }
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Output: in console, it shows nothing.

when I enter the wrong name if() condition is working fine but else condition does not fetch any data any modifications?

Comment: Remove your call to `rs.previous()` and switch to a `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rs.next() advances to the next record. You call it twice, once in the if and once in the while.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks.